# Questions about homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Since I just have a very brief introduction of homotopy in topology course, I have the following questions:

1. Homotopy seems to be similar to homeomorphism, which studies the topological property of two spaces, but the definition of homotopy doesn't relate two different spaces. Like many popular science books, they usually use "we can continuously change a coffee cup to a doughnut", but the definition just tells us that I can do it in that space, how to relate to other spaces? Is there any direct way, like homeomorphism which uses bijective mappings, to relate two spaces?
2. Why is homotopy important in algebraic topology? (would like to have some not so abstract examples) Homeomorphism is quite clear that if two spaces are homeomorphic, we can say a lot of properties which hold for both spaces, structure-preserving. Then how about homotopy? What is the difference between homotopy and homeomorphism? (I also heard about somethings called homology, if possible, would also like to ask the differences between these three words)

Sorry that I'm quite lost in studying topolgoy and I may be asking it in a confusing way, still hope somebody can clear my confusions.

Thank you!

Comment: one of the reasons homotopy is important is because most of the algebraic invariants like cohomology, homotopy groups are can roughly distinguish spaces only upto homotopy. Also it is usually very difficult to check if two spaces are homeomorphic but checking whether they are homotopic can be more tractable.

Comment: Klaus Jänich answers this question quite well in his very conversational book "Topology" -- I recommend that you read it when you have time.  As happymath noted, determining homeomorphism can be very difficult,  whereas the computation of topological invariants (e.g., homotopy groups, homology groups, the Euler characteristic), is often much more easier.  Among reasons that Jänich gives for the importance of the notion of homotopy is the "homotopy invariance of most algebraic topological functors."  Take a look at his book's sections V.6 and V.7 and it'll help dispel much of your confusion.